# Selenium, Beautiful Soup Find Most Similar

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I am trying to search a business name in a database, then download the company records using Selenium. The issue is when I search a company, sometimes there are multiple similar results/companies, so I cannot write Selenium to statically choose the same thing every time. How can I identify all results, then choose the "most similar" option.

For example, if I searched the entity "Bowman Real Estate LLC" the browser would return three results in a table, "Bowman Real Estate LLC", "Bowman Real Estate and Development LLC" and "Bowman Real Estate & Development Group LLC"

I need to be able to identify all options in page source, then determine which is most similar and click on it to advance to next page and download. This is all I have so far:

```
driver.get('https://www.sosnc.gov/search/index/corp')
entity = "BOWMAN REAL ESTATE LLC"

try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="SearchCriteria"]')))
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="SearchCriteria"]').send_keys(entity)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='SubmitButton']").click()

except TimeoutException:
    print("Loading took too much time! - 1")

try:
    web_url = driver.page_source
    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(web_url, 'html.parser')
```

Comment: regex `"Bowman Real Estate .*LLC"`

Comment: Determining the "similarity" of two strings is a very complex issue; take a look at https://itnext.io/string-similarity-the-basic-know-your-algorithms-guide-3de3d7346227

Comment: I think that the first one is the most similar ?